# Dragonfly how resize small image and fill gaps with some color?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, dragonfly-gem

Is it possible to resize with **Dragonfly gem** small image 70x70 to 160x70 and fill gaps with specific color 
I try some recipes from here http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.ImageMagick.html

something like **image.process(:resize, '160x70#', :background_color => 'transparent')**

Is there any way?